# Regex to remove statment from string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to regex and am having some issues trying to remove 2 strings from a string of text.

I'm using python3 and have tried the following.

```
'\W*(Command|exited|with|status|0)\W*
```

To match the string: `Command exited with status 0`

I am also looking for the regex to match the following.

```
=== stdout ===
```

I have tried:

```
'\W*(===|stdout|===)\W*
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: `Command|exited|with|status|0`: `|` is "or" not a word separator.

Comment: you don't even need regexes here. Just use `your_string = your_string.replace("=== stdout ===","")`, same thing for the other example

Comment: Is single quote a typo? otherwise it matches words in that string.

Comment: Create/debug your regex by starting from just the first element of the pattern and ONLY once that matches what you expect THEN add the next element of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'string = re.sub('=== stdout ===', '', string)' to sub your desired text for nothing (''). Here is some example code:

```
import re

string = 'i think New Roman"=== stdout ===>but I don\'t he=Command exited with status 0"Arial">fun stuff'

string = re.sub('Command exited with status 0', '', string)
string = re.sub('=== stdout ===', '', string)

print(string)
```

Remember to use '\|' in your string instead of just '|'

Comment: Downvoted because you replace any instance of “with” or “command”, not the requested string “Command exited with status”

Comment: I changed the code slightly to better match the requested string. I did not realize the was using '|' in place of ' '(spaces).

Comment: Thanks guys, let me try this one sec.

Comment: Ok so that did work however I did forget one more, specifically (no stderr), when I tried re.sub('(nostder)', '', string) it works, however, it leaves the () and just removes the nostder.